# Is this the correct way to reuse the redis client?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have created a redis client module named `redisConnection.js`. It's contents are as follows

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

exports.exposeConnection = function(){

 return redis;

};
```

Now whenever I want to get make use of redis I just `require` the module and call the `exposeConnection` method. I wanted to know if this is right way to reuse the connection. I am hoping that redis connection is being instantiated only once and not every time I call the module. If not is there a better way reuse it?

Comment: Can't really say whether it's "*right*." But, Node does [cache modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) based [on their file path](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats). So, as long as you don't have multiple `redisConnection.js` files, only one connection should be created among all `require()`s.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks. Module caching was what I was looking for. Could you add an answer?

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question but it could be one way to achieve that client accessible throughout the application by doing - 
`var redis = require('redis');
GLOBAL._REDISCLIENT = redis.createClient(port, server);`

Comment: @Pranav Thanks for pointing this out. I did not know you could create GLOBAL variables in node js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's almost similar to what I would I do(and what I have done in my previous apps).

Although instead of exposing it through a function I would just do this:

```
module.exports = require('redis').createClient();
```

So then later I can just do `redis = require('./local-redis')` instead of `redis = require('./local-redis').exposeConnection()`.

This is a very simple but reliable architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I had almost given up on this question.

Comment: Be careful with using a single connection if you're using transaction commands such as `WATCH`, `EXEC` , `MULTI`. If the single connection is used concurrently, your code will likely be incorrect. You will need separate connections for correctness.