# Where to connect to Redis within Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

Does the redis or connect-redis offer any connection pooling?  I'm not sure the best place to initiate a connection within an express web app.

Is it within server.js? or do I need to initiate a connection on each controller that makes a query to redis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311934/is-this-the-correct-way-to-reuse-the-redis-client) question before but I never really got an answer. Here is what I do.

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

exports.exposeConnection = function(){

 return redis;

};
```

This will open redis connection once and you can use anywhere within your application.

Comment: Yeah, singleton makes sense (especially with redis being single-threaded), but it doesn't seem very elegant.